# Does the scalar curvature vanish whenever the stress energy tensor is traceless?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Assuming the cosmological constant is zero, the Einstein equations are:
$ R_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu \nu} = 8 \pi T_{\mu \nu} $. Using the definition of the scalar curvature, we may obtain:

$ R = R^\nu_{\; \nu} = g^{\mu \nu} R_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} R g^{\mu \nu} g_{\mu \nu} + 8 \pi g^{\mu \nu} T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} R \delta^{\nu}_{\; \nu} +8\pi T^{\nu}_{\; \nu} = 2R $

Since $ \delta^{\nu}_{\; \nu} = 4 $ (four spacetime dimensions) and $ T^{\nu}_{\; \nu} = 0 $ (as we assumed the stress-energy tensor is traceless); thus, $R=0$.

Is this result true? Although the computation is trivial, I have not seen it mentioned anywhere, therefore I must assume I have made some error which I cannot detect.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor#Trace

Comment: See eq. (19.42) [here](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf).